# Chrome / opera browser extension on page load, load another page in background to get data

Tags: google-chrome-extension, opera-extension

Is there a way to get data from other pages? I mean when you open specific page, the script runs a search on the web to look for data and then you insert that data into the loaded page you loaded before?

Example would be say you looking to buy a chair, you looking at one seller web page but the extension looks up prices from other sellers and shows a graph or values, then you click on the value to go to that other seller page.

From what i understand you can manipulate DOM of opened tabs, but is there a way to load DOM from another page that is not in the opened tab?

Comment: The background script can load other URLs and parse the HTML response into DOM, see also https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: thanks, looked it up but it seems i still lack knowledge to properly understand how to use it. JS is something im not familiar with. And from what i tested, the site that i want to read has cloudflare ddos protection, so i have to solve the task for a cookie and do all kinds of stuff..in order to get to the site's content.